# Simplify $\displaystyle\prod_{j=1}^{K}\exp(-2\pi\lambda_j(sp_j)^{2/\alpha}\int_0^{\infty}r\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t(1+r^{\alpha})}dtdr)$.

Tags: gamma-function, poisson-process

An equation involving the poisson point process is formulated as:
$$\prod_{j=1}^{K}\exp(-2\pi\lambda_j(sp_j)^{2/\alpha}\int_0^{\infty}r\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t(1+r^{\alpha})}dtdr).$$

Some algebraic manipulations are carried out and the equation is rewritten as:

$$\exp(-s^{2/\alpha}C(\alpha)\sum_{i=1}^{K}\lambda_ip_i^{2/\alpha}),$$ where $$C(\alpha)=\frac{2\pi^2 csc(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})}{\alpha}.$$

I only know the manipulation is related to Gamma function. I want to know the datails about the manipulation.

Thanks a lot! :  )

Comment: But I am getting $C(\alpha)=\frac{2\pi^2 \csc(\frac{2\pi}{\alpha})}{\alpha}$ assuming $p_j$ and $P_i$ are the same. Also, it seems that @Sebastiano edited the position of brackets. Could you check if the question is still what you wanted to ask?

Comment: @SameerBaheti I'm sorry if I done a mistake. I do a rollback for my edit.

Comment: @Sebastiano Thanks for your edit and  I have improved the expression above. :  )

Comment: @Sameer Baheti Thanks for your comment. I have reviewed and improved  the question . In fact, $p_j$ and $p_j$ are the same, the answer you got is correct. Can you give a specific derivation process? This problem really bother me. Thans a lot.

Comment: @hengzhu I'm very glady to help you and all users :-) My best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focus on simplifying $$2\pi\int_0^{\infty}r\int_0^{\infty}e^{-t(1+r^{\alpha})}dtdr
=2\pi\int_0^{\infty}\frac r{1+r^\alpha}dr$$

Substitute $u=\frac1{1+r^\alpha}$ to get a [Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function) form $$\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\int_0^1(1-u)^{\frac2\alpha-1}u^\frac2\alpha du=\frac{2\pi}{\alpha}\Gamma\left(1-\frac2\alpha\right)\Gamma\left(\frac2\alpha\right)$$

Use the [Gamma function property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Properties) $$\Gamma\left(1-z\right)\Gamma\left(z\right)=\pi\csc(\pi z), z\not\in\mathbb Z$$